# Parse Airdna.co Using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the data from the website "Airdna.co" I'm struggling to get the data. I managed this code as below but I get always  a None value:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup from bs4 
import NavigableString 
import requests import os, os.path, csv
                                                                                                                         url='https://www.airdna.co/market-data/app/fr/new-aquitaine/bordeaux/overview'

url = 'https://www.airdna.co/market-data/app/fr/new-aquitaine/bordeaux/overview'
response = requests.get(url)
encodedText = response.text.encode("latin-1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(encodedText, "html.parser") 
dl_data = soup.find_all("div",class_="overall-box__value ")

for data in list(zip(soup.find_all("div",class_="overall-box__value")[0::2],soup.find_all("div",class_="overall-box__value    ")[1::2],soup.find_all("div",class_="overall-box__value ")[2::2])):
    ADRate, ORate, Revenue = data
    ADRate = ADRate.string.encode('utf-8')
    ORate= ORate.string.encode('utf-8')
    Revenue = Revenue.string.encode('utf-8') 
    print ' , '.join([ADRate,ORate,Revenue])
```

[This is the link for the website.](https://www.airdna.co/market-data/app/fr/new-aquitaine/bordeaux/overview)

After displaying the soup variable, I realized that the body is empty:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(encodedText,"html.parser")
```

Can anybody show and explain how I would do this?

Answer (score 1):

The data on that page is generated dynamically via JavaScript. You'll need to use something like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) to scrape it. Once you've installed it, try running the script below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.airdna.co/market-data/app/fr/new-aquitaine/bordeaux/overview")

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

values = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "overall-box__value"})
target_list = []
for value in values:
    target_list.append(value.text)

output = ' , '.join(target_list)
print(output)
```

This outputs:

```
€73 , 78% , €1,192
```

Comment: I want to extract the same value from web site "https://www.airbnb.fr/s/La-Rochelle/homes?allow_override%5B%5D=&s_tag=0UvPBFDq&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes"  but i  got the value none

Comment: That link does not have the same elements you were looking for in the first one. You will need to adapt the script to suit whatever elements you're trying to obtain.